# Create List Item not working in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online

Using SP Online trying to create a simple workflow that triggers on item creation (in list A) to create list items in 2 different lists (list B & list C). i know the workflow is triggering as the first list item is created (list B), however the second list item is not created (list C).

Does anyone have any experience with this or suggestions where i should look to resolve?

Comment: Please add some screen shots of your Workflow code

Comment: Have you found any errors in log

Comment: Ok thanks for suggesting the log. i havnt used that until now. The error message is: Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.

Comment: are you using lookup column in workflow

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: Yes, one of the columns in List C is lookup. I wasnt trying to set the colum in the workflow, but i think that may be the problem = it wont allow a blank value

Comment: That usually happens when you use an empty field and set it to be something other than a string. please check my updated answer

Comment: create a variable, put the information from the "Look Up Column" action into the variable, check if the variable is null, and if it is null set it to some default value that you decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In above screen shot, creating items in **List B** and **list C** on item when new list item created in list A.

1. Use action Create item
2. Add list name
3. Add fields and values

   **Updated Answer**

That usually happens when you use an empty field and set it to be something other than a string. For example, when you use a lookup value you can use it as a string, a lookup id, or a lookup value. If that lookup hasn't been set, lookup id and lookup value will give you a coercion error.

Same with a people field - if you try to use it as a 'Display Name' in workflow and the field is empty, you get the error.

If you are using Lookup column filed in workflow.
 then create a variable, put the information from the "Look Up Column" action into the variable, check if the variable is null, and if it is null set it to some default value that you decide.

[Ref Article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ac6913c4-396b-4e7c-a42f-ee78656c7532/coercion-failed-unable-to-transform-the-input-lookup-data-into-the-requested-type)